# What would usually happen if Jack and Vika return to the Tet in Oblivion?

Tags: plot-explanation, oblivion

Wonder if the writers have thought about it. Are they killed and new clones are sent instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most likely, yes.**

While never expressly shown it's very heavily hinted that the Jack and Vika are expendable and very easily replaceable, and in-fact there have been many generations of clones.

Tet continuously asks them "Are you still an effective team?"

Under the specific condition where Vika responds "No, we are not an effective team." A number of drones are immediately activated to exterminate both Jack and Vika, likely to be replaced by two new clones.

Under the circumstance that Jack or Vika discover the truth behind Tet and become insubordinate (which includes trying to return to the ship), they will likely be disposed of and replaced with new clones.

The only reason Jack is able to make it to the ship unharmed at the end of the movie is because Jack promises to bring Julia to Tet.

Comment: Why only 5 years?

Comment: @Aurimas 5 years of what?

Comment: 5 years tour and then they pressumambly killed..

Comment: @Aurimas; that is a separate question, and would also likely get marked as being opinion based: The answer to that as I see it is that's how long the clones are typically reliable for. After about 5 years one or both of the clones defect and need to be replaced anyway. I have a longer explanation as to why, but it wont fit in a comment. It also explains Tet's interest with Julia. You can either attempt to post this as another question or we can discuss in chat.

Comment: Considering implanted memories are at play here - the 5 year tour is questionable - they should be implanted with 4 years of memory and replaced after only a year